# Softlayer API- How to track the status of gateway appliance after I ordered one?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using softlayer api to  place an vyatta pair, which is network gateway, how can I know when the provison is complete?

I read an article [here](https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/going-further-softlayer-api-python-client-part-3), but still not  dont know in the last part where did the gateway name comes from?

can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The name of the gateway is assigned at the creation moment, it is the hostname that you used in your order. In the case you are ordening a high availability gateway (2 nodes) the name is the first hostname that you set in your order.

Regards